# R: smallest distance between an element of vector a and an element of vector b

Tags: r

`a` and `b` are two vectors of real numbers.

They do not necessarily have the same length.

The distance between the `i`th element of `a` and the `j`th element of `b` is defined as `abs(a[i] - b[j])`

How would you compute the smallest distance between any element of `a` and any element of `b` without explicit loops?

Here is what I did: `min(sapply(X=1:length(b), FUN=function(x) abs(a - b[x])))`.

However, I have the feeling there is something better to do...

Comment: @Joshua: a counterexample: a = c(9 5 6), b = c(6, 9). Thanks

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich the OP wants the minimum distance between any point pair, not the distance between the point pair of the minimums of each vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an attempt:

```
a <- c(9,5,6); b <- c(6,9)
# a
#[1] 9 5 6
# b
#[1] 6 9

combos <- sapply(b,function(x) abs(x-a))
# or an alternative
combos <- abs(outer(a,b,FUN="-"))
```

You could then get the minimum distance with:

```
min(combos)
```

If you wanted to get the respective indexes of the minimum values you could do:

```
which(combos==min(combos),arr.ind=TRUE)

# each matrix row has the 2 indexes for the minimums
# first column is 'a' index, second is 'b' index
#      row col
# [1,]   3   1
# [2,]   1   2
```

Comment: I like the "outer solution" :-)

Comment: Than you should probably accept that as your answer, the green tick mark is to show which answer helped you best.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use the `dist` function to create a distance matrix, and then find the minimum distance in that. This is probably much faster than an explicit loop in R (including `sapply`).

```
a = runif(23)
b = runif(10)
d_matrix = as.matrix(dist(cbind(a,b)))
d_matrix[d_matrix == 0] <- NA
sqrt(min(d_matrix, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Note that `cbind` recycles the smaller vector. So this function is probably not optimal, but for vectors that do not differ that much in size still much fast than an explicit loop.

And to find which pair of elements had this distance (although the recycling introduces some challenges here):

```
which(d_matrix == min(d_matrix, na.rm = TRUE), arr.ind = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks! I think it does not work when a and b have different lengths. Is it possible to adapt it?

Comment: When `a` and `b` are not of equal length, `cbind` will simply repeat the smaller vector. Therefore, `min(d_matrix)` will still return the minimum. I adapted my example.

Comment: Ok regarding the length issue. A last thing: when a = c(7, 9, 11) and b = c(5, 13), your code returns 4. Am I missing something?

Comment: `dist` uses the squared distance, taking the square root of the minimum gets you the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

One-liner should work here: `min(abs(outer(a, b, "-")))`

Comment: Very good :-) I accepted @thelatemail's answer which suggests outer first. Anyway, +1 and thank you very much!